# How to restore/recover a booted medium to USB

Tags: usb

I have booted a USB with an ISO-file, now I want to recover it so I can use it as a normally working USB. What are the code used for this process?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use *mkusb* and the wipe menu, where you can select to restore the drive to a standard USB pendrive for storage of data with an MSDOS partition table and one partition with the FAT32 file system.

See the following links

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[mkusb/wipe](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe)

Comment: +1 for using mkusb for USB cleaning, especially if drive has any ISO9660 partitions.